# Titanium : Need HTTP connection timedout status code

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

Do we have any option to find out HTTP connection timedout status code exactly ? HTTP connection timedout and bad request url BOTH gives response code 0.Is there a way to identify connection timedout uniquely?

```
 var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
   backgroundColor : '#ffffff'
 });
 var url = 'https://www.google.com';
 if (Ti.Network.online) {
 var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
 timeout : 1000,
 validatesSecureCertificate : false
 });
 xhr.onload = function(e) {

 alert('onload:');
 };
 xhr.onerror = function(e) {
 alert('e.error:' + e.error + ':status:' + xhr.status);
 };
 xhr.open('GET', url);
 xhr.send(); }
 self.open();
```

The above code is giving TimedOut status code as 0 in case of iphone, not like 408. But in case of Android TimedOut is not happening.

Comment: What do you mean with BAD Request? BAD REQUEST usually returns 400 and not 0.

Comment: I have updated questioin by adding some code snippet please check it.

Comment: if the url is wrong you'll also get 0 as response i think. but there is no way to detect whether there is a timeout or a wrong url. you can check this only by analyzing repsonse time but this is not possible in titanium i think.

Answer (score 0):

In Android ,  there are 2 cases to consider incase of Timeout. 2 types of errors are observed,

In logs,
Case 1:

> TiHTTPClient: (TiHttpClient-9) [7700,93840] HTTP Error
>   (java.net.SocketTimeoutException): timeout [ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
>
> alert('e.error:' + e.error + ':status:' + xhr.status); gives output as
>
> e.error:timeout  :status:0...

Case 2:
TiHTTPClient: (TiHttpClient-14) [53148,203910] HTTP Error (java.net.SocketTimeoutException): SSL handshake timed out
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SSL handshake timed out

> alert('e.error:' + e.error + ':status:' + xhr.status); gives output as
>
> e.error:SSL handshake timed out:status:0
>
> so by checking the,
>
> ((e.error).toLowerCase() == "timeout" || (e.error).toLowerCase() ==
>   "sslhandshake timed out"),

we can
capturethe timeout scenario and display proper message accordingly.